# Vb.net error current connection is in open state

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting the error that connection's current state is open in vb.net. The connection is with ms access as database. Tried lot to solve. Need help.

```
    Private Sub addnew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addnew.Click
    pro = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ashwi\source\repos\Database\bin\Debug\daksystem.mdb"
    connstring = pro
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
    myconnection.Open()
    command = "insert into [dispatch] ([Dispatch Number], [Dispatch Date], [Document Type], [Subject], [Sender], [Receiver] values " & "('" & dispnumber.Text & "', '" & DateTimePicker.Text & "', '" & doctype.Text & "', '" & subject.Text & "', '" & dsender.Text & "', '" & receiver.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Dispatch Number", CType(dispnumber.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Dispatch Date", CType(DateTimePicker.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Document Type", CType(doctype.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Subject", CType(subject.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Sender", CType(dsender.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("receiver", CType(receiver.Text, String)))
    MsgBox("Are you sure To save the data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    myconnection.Close()
    dispnumber.Clear()
    doctype.Text = String.Empty
    subject.Clear()
    dsender.Text = String.Empty
    receiver.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think that you're not on topic

This isn't access-vba question tag.

Please correct that

Answer (score 0):

try this way
in the beginning of the sub:

```
Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ashwi\source\repos\Database\bin\Debug\daksystem.mdb")
    cnn.Open()
```

and in the last of the sub:

```
cnn.close()
end using
```

another way:
just replace this line:

```
 myconnection.Open()
```

with:

```
If myconnection.State = ConnectionState.close Then
 myconnection.Open()
End If
```